# XML unmarshalling with Castor and Grails

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy, castor

I have a grails project that contains a few domain objects. I am using a java project in this code which can parse a document for me. The controller that calls that Java project is using JAXB to generate XML from the object returned by the Java project. 
I want to use this XML document (which is generated after some text parsing, using JAXB) to populate my Domain classes in my grails project. How does this work in grails? Can I use something like Castor, and create a mapping using the names of my groovy classes? The idea is I want to generate new entries in the database and save it for the user based on whatever text was parsed out of the document they uploaded.

How does this even work in grails anyway? Can I create a new Domain object from another object's controller with something like

```
 Project p = new Project();
```

and then do a `p.save()`?

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes. Domains and Controllers don't have to be one-to-one. You can have a domain class `Foo` and a `BarController` that works with `Foo`s and be just fine.

Comment: Are you bound to Castor, or are you open to other frameworks? I can give you an example using XStream; I've worked with it before.

Comment: I am open to anything - Castor was just what was suggested to me - I have not worked with XML very much before. I am basically building a text parser that will pull info out of a document that we have corresponding Domain objects in Grails for.  The parser I wrote in Java, and I called it from my groovy controller. It returns a String with my XML representation in it. That is what I want to map to the Grails Domain Objects. If you have a small grails project example showing this it would be great. I also have the controllers for the grails domain objects to be created "manually" as well.

Comment: Why are you considering switching from JAXB?  There are alternate JAXB implementations that may have the mapping functionality you need.  For example http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Castor Core and Castor XML jars from [here](http://www.castor.org/download.html) and put them in the `lib` directory (there's probably a better way to manage this dependency using Grails' [dependency management](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution), but this one's a quick and dirty).

With [Castor introspection mode](http://www.castor.org/xml-framework.html#Introspection-mode) you don't need to worry about creating mapping files if your XML matches up nicely with your domains. Here's an example:

**grails-app/domain/MyDomain.groovy**

```
class MyDomain {
    String foo
    String bar
}
```

**grails-app/controllers/MyController.groovy**

```
import org.exolab.castor.xml.Unmarshaller
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

class MyController {

    def myAction = {
        def xml = '''
<myDomain>
  <foo>My Foo String</foo>
  <bar>My Bar String</bar>
</myDomain>
'''
        def reader = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.bytes).newReader()
        def domain = (MyDomain)Unmarshaller.unmarshal(MyDomain.class, reader)
        domain.save()

        def count = MyDomain.countByFoo('My Foo String')

        render "Found $count results"
    }
}
```

Navigate to `localhost:8080/appname/my/myAction` and it should display "Found N results", N > 0.

Comment: Based on reading about the introspection - lets say my XML file has a lot of stuff in it - will this be smart enough to see that since I am casting to (MyDomain) type for the unmarshaller, that it will dig through the XML file to find those objects?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your XML would be? That might help me understand your intentions a little better.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8Qb1ewdM Here is a pastebin of a sample output. The domain classes would be Education, Employer, Project, Tool, Skill. If it is an embedded classtype here, such as project, then Employer holds a list of those Objects, that way the right project is linked to the right employer

Comment: Hmm, a little more complex than I thought. I don't have time to work up an answer that will meet your input exactly, but I think my answer in its current form will give you a start. You can use Groovy's XmlSlurper to grab portions of that XML and then use Castor for each piece to create domains.

Comment: Thanks, I am using it as a start, and doing a little further googling too